# EBUSY error while installing cordova 3.2 with nodejs

Tags: cordova

I am using windows 7 and got error while executing 
`npm install -g cordova`   command and then it shows following error>>

```
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EBUSY, unlink 'C:\nodejs\cordova'
npm ERR! error rolling back  cordova@3.2.0-0.1.0 { [Error: EBUSY, unlink 'C:\nod
ejs\cordova'] errno: 10, code: 'EBUSY', path: 'C:\\nodejs\\cordova' }
npm ERR! Error: EISDIR, open 'C:\nodejs\cordova'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\n
pm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! cwd C:\nodejs\cordova
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.16
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.8
npm ERR! path C:\nodejs\cordova
npm ERR! code EISDIR
npm ERR! errno 28
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\nodejs\cordova\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

any idea on this kind of problem??

Comment: I Solved that problem you need to run "npm install -g cordova" command from where you install nodeJS not from any sub-folder Suppose I installed nodeJS in "MyNode" folder then I will run "npm install -g cordova" command from c:\MyNode>npm install -g cordova

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to Answer my own question
I Solved that problem you need to run "npm install -g cordova" command from where you install nodeJS not from any sub-folder Suppose I installed nodeJS in "MyNode" folder then I will run "npm install -g cordova" command from c:\MyNode>npm install -g cordova

Comment: ==> Try this first <==
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36566236/npm-install-error-code-ebusy-errono-4082/45757541#45757541