# npm install error code EBUSY errono -4082

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am running windows7 and have just installed the following...

```
c:\design_centre_dev\workspace>node -v
v5.10.1

c:\design_centre_dev\workspace>npm -v
3.8.6
```

I'm having issues running npm install on my node project which one of my fellow dev's says he has no trouble with and should work for me.

When I run npm install i am getting errors like...

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\rriviere\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.10.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
npm ERR! path c:\design_centre_dev\workspace\node_modules\path-type
npm ERR! code EBUSY
npm ERR! errno -4082
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rename 'c:\design_centre_dev\workspace\node_modules\path-type' -> 'c:\design_centre_dev\workspace\node_module
s\.path-type.DELETE'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

It seems to throw these same types of errors for modules asynch,path_type and isarray and does not want to get past them.

Can anyone suggest what might be wrong?

---

### EDIT

Thanks for the suggestion of this thread possibly being answered somewhere else. I had a look and I believe it is a different problem. I think this because I've been investigating further today and I think the problem is that the node_modules directory which npm is creating. The permissions on that directory don't seem to be right. I think this might be an issue and probably a new thread so I'll close this one and create a new.

Comment: After doing more investigation I have narrowed the cause of the problem to something more specific.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you have open that node module file in your editor then just **close the file** from the editor

Or

**Close Editor Software**

Then **Try again**

Answer (score 4):

The cause of this was windows permissions problems. My work computer did not have privilleges to do certain things. When I moved to my personal mac everything just worked.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when tried to uninstall/re-install a module on Win10 VM. "npm cache clean", as suggested by some, did not work. Restarting the system resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This issue may links to country boycott or computer limitation. I live in a country which is boycott and I could rise that with turn on VPN and then do the process of installation. Please follow this:

1. `npm run cache clean ---force` (remove `node_modules`)
2. Turn on VPN (set it based on country which isn't boycott)
3. `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem for 3 days and got this solution for it...

It's because of old files lying in your c drive:

Follow the steps below and try, It will work for sure.

problem:

npm ERR! Errno: -4048,
npm ERR! code: ‘EPERM’,
npm ERR! syscall: ‘scandir’,

solution:

Uninstall node with node uninstaller ( find it from run cmd )

Then...

1. Delete the npmrc file and delete the C:\Users\Administrator.npmrc file ( if don't find leave it )
2. Delete npm-cache folder from - C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming
3. Delete npm folder from - C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming

Restart your system and install fresh NodeJS and run this command in cmd: npm cache clean -–force to ensure the cache is cleared.

That's your ready to go now...

If you still face a problem feel free to get in touch with me @ishaiknadeem username on any platform

Answer (score 0):

Just close the terminal and turn on a new one, then 'npm install' it works on me.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem today. I found that is because I npm run in a terminal and npm install in another terminal. The file was occupied. I just delete the node_modules and npm run again.

Answer (score 0):

This is an underlying issue of Anti Malware software blocking your application from connecting to node package manager (npm).

I am using Bullguard and disabling my Antivirus seemed to do the trick!